# OS Translator II in QGIS failing to import - OGR version issues?

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr, os-mastermap

I'm trying to import mastermap into QGIS (on Mac OS) using the OS Translator II plugin. I'm a newbie!

I'm running QGIS 2.18.15, with GDAL/OGR 2.1.3, and the OS Translator II plugin was downloaded through the plugin manager.

QGIS was installed from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis, and I installed the four additional packages that were included in the bundle, including "1 GDAL Complete.pkg" - which appears to be /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.11

Firstly when I run the OS Translator import it complained that ogr2ogr wasn't found. I'm not sure why it was not using the version installed with QGIS. I temporarily fixed it by modifying the import_task.py script to give it the explicit path:

```
joe:OSTranslatorII root# pwd
/Users/joe/.qgis2/python/plugins/OSTranslatorII
joe:OSTranslatorII root# diff -u import_task.py.orig import_task.py
--- import_task.py.orig 2018-02-11 11:39:06.000000000 +0000
+++ import_task.py  2018-02-11 08:23:56.000000000 +0000
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@
                 cmd += arg + ' '
             print 'Starting %s' % cmd

-        self.process.start('ogr2ogr', self.args)
+        self.process.start('/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework//Versions/2.1/Programs/ogr2ogr', self.args)
     if not self.process.waitForStarted():
         raise Exception('Failed to start process. Please ensure you have gdal/ogr2ogr installed')
```

Then it could find the tool, but it complained that the ogr2ogr line options were wrong:

```
Args: ['-overwrite', '-lyr_transaction', '-f', 'PostgreSQL', '--config', 'PG_USE_COPY', 'YES', '--config', 'GML_GFS_TEMPLATE', '/var/folders/p4/rjqvjlbx2rz1cs9x74f0tb6m0000gp/T/1518284450.86.gfs', "PG:dbname='test' host='' port='5432' active_schema=os_mm_tmp user='postgres' password='XXXX'", '/vsigzip//Users/joe/.qgis2/python/plugins/OSTranslatorII/gfs/OS Mastermap Topography (v9) Pioneer.gz', '-lco', 'OVERWRITE=YES', '-lco', 'SPATIAL_INDEX=OFF', '-lco', 'PRECISION=NO', '--config', 'GML_EXPOSE_FID', 'NO']
Stdout: Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
           [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where]
           [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>] [-dialect dialect]
           [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID]
           [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-geomfield field]
           [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
           [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
           dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
           [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name] [-nlt type] [-dim 2|3|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]

Note: ogr2ogr --long-usage for full help.

Stderr: 
    FAILURE: Unknown option name '-lyr_transaction'

  Args: ['-append', '-lyr_transaction', '-f', 'PostgreSQL', '--config', 'PG_USE_COPY', 'YES', '--config', 'GML_GFS_TEMPLATE', '/var/folders/p4/rjqvjlbx2rz1cs9x74f0tb6m0000gp/T/1518284450.86.gfs', "PG:dbname='test' host='' port='5432' active_schema=os_mm_tmp user='postgres' password='XXXX'", '/tmp/2998191/2998191-summary.gml', '--config', 'GML_EXPOSE_FID', 'NO']
  Stdout: Usage: ogr2ogr [--help-general] [-skipfailures] [-append] [-update]
           [-select field_list] [-where restricted_where]
           [-progress] [-sql <sql statement>] [-dialect dialect]
           [-preserve_fid] [-fid FID]
           [-spat xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-geomfield field]
           [-a_srs srs_def] [-t_srs srs_def] [-s_srs srs_def]
           [-f format_name] [-overwrite] [[-dsco NAME=VALUE] ...]
           dst_datasource_name src_datasource_name
           [-lco NAME=VALUE] [-nln name] [-nlt type] [-dim 2|3|layer_dim] [layer [layer ...]]
```

I'm guessing that OS Translator II is implemented against a different version of ogr2ogr.

If anyone else has experienced this problem, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've made some progress.

I installed the QGIS 2.14.21-1 version of QGIS from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

This appears to come with a different version of GCAL (/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework//Versions/2.1). I'm not sure why the newer version of QGIS was packaged with an older version of GCAL. (Maybe it wasn't, maybe it was me?)

After hacking the import_task.py to point to the different version of ogr2ogr, the import now runs fine.